# Nginx dynamic url rewrite location

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I wanna make something like that. So when I try to login, my system navigate me to `http://www.example.com/username` and I wanna rewrite to `../admin/index.php`

I have this done before in .htaccess but in webserver nginx isn't working.

```
    location = /username {
        rewrite ^ /admin/index.php;
    }
```

My php link to this location looks like:

```
<?php echo SITEURL . "/" . $user->username; ?>
```

When I manualy change `/username` instead my real username all working like I want, but how can I make my url rewrite working with variable username from database? Thanks for any help